# I get an error if I insert this function -imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation - (GPUImageLookupFilter)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gpuimage

I have problems with implementing the `GPUImageLookupFilter`.
I get an error in this line of code:`UIImage *adjustedImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation];`

It says (error): 
`"No visible @interface for 'GPUImageLookupFilter' declares the selector 'imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation'"`

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)filter1:(id)sender;
{
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookup = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:imgView];

GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lookup_Invert.png"]];
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
[stillImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];
[lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];


[stillImageSource processImage];
[lookupFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[lookupImageSource processImage];

UIImage *adjustedImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [No @interface for 'GPUImageLookupFilter' declares the selector 'imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162015/no-interface-for-gpuimagelookupfilter-declares-the-selector-imagefromcurrent)

Comment: possible duplicate of [No visible @interface for 'GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput>' declares the selector 'imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609421/no-visible-interface-for-gpuimageoutputgpuimageinput-declares-the-selector)

Comment: Only the code is the same but the question is another. Can you tell me the correct code line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please read through the documentation I've written on [the very first page of the project](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). You'll save yourself a lot of headaches by reading that before progressing further. Blindly copying code from the Internet is not a great way to build an application.

As I explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618060/19679) that I pointed you to in your previous question, the way that the framework handles framebuffers has changed, so a lot of the sample code you find out there is now obsolete. For processing still images using a lookup filter, you need to send `-useNextFrameForImageCapture` to your lookup filter right before you trigger `-processImage` in the above. `-processImage` causes the initial image to cascade through the chained filter operations, and you need to tell your end filter that you'll be pulling an image from it before you trigger that processing.

Once that is done, you can then extract your image using `-imageFromCurrentFramebuffer` or `-imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:` (note the parameter in the latter, because your code above won't compile).

Again, please read the resources I have linked to on the front page of GPUImage's GitHub repository and from my previous answer before proceeding further. You really should understand how this operates, which is why I'm not spoon-feeding you the code you need here.

Comment: Ok, I have read the documentation. And edited my code. Please have a look at it (I replaced the old code in the question). But now I get an other error. Maybe I don't undestand all because english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: @user3550084 - This latest error is because GPUImageFilter is the name of a class, not an instance of it. `-useNextFrameForImageCapture` is an instance method, not a class method, so you need to call that on your filter instance, not GPUImageFilter as a class.

Comment: I added the instance of GPUImageLookupFilter and now it works. But I get another error in this line of code (I've updated the question): UIImage *adjustedImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation];

Comment: Now it works. I forgot to set the orientation. Thanks for your help!